# how to create a persistence arraylist structure in java?

Tags: java, persistence

I want to make a simple persistence data structure about arraylist, this is what I am thinking:

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    public T element;
    
    private LinkedList(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
    
    private LinkedList<T> AddElememt(T element){
        var lc = new LinkedList<>();
        lc.add(element);
        return lc;
    }
```

This it not the correct way, how can I go to change it? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use ArrayList or LinkedList?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by “simple persistence data structure”. Edit your Question to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Java already offers a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) class. This is one of a few implementations of the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interface. [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) is another.

```
List< String > animals = new java.util.LinkedList<>() ;
animals.add( "dog" ) ;
animals.add( "cat" ) ;
```

If you want a non-modifiable list of a few items, use [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E)).

```
List< String > animals = List.of( "dog" , "cat" ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java provides [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class out of box.

But you you need to implement your own *array-list* data structure, right?
You can use the following clear implementation as example: https://howtodoinjava.com/data-structure/list-implementation-example-in-java/;